# Element Style not changing inside funtion

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
function AutoHider(){
   var Word = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
   for (var Count = 0;Count<Word.length;Count++){
    if(Word[Count].innerHTML === ""){
        Word[Count].style.display = 'none';
    }
   }
}
```

i have a list of 32 article tags each for an alphabet letter for a custom hobby dictionary
i manuanly added a lot of words to each tag but what i want is for the JS to automatically put the display of the tags that have no content in them to none so i made this AutoHider() function and attached it to a button by onclick event the "Word" variable is a set of 33 article tags with classname "word"
then i create a loop that counts from 0 to 32 and puts the number in a [] after Word to act as a selector because it cant navigate all that article tags by tiself and in the statement i decleared if the innerHTML is empty change .style.display to none
but it does not work

Important Note : the function all the classnames and ID and variables as well as the loop works fine because i used a different code in if statement for example puting letter A in every single empty article tag and it worked only thing that does not work is changing the style

sorry if sentence is messy

i tried different task than chaning style such as showing an alert or filling article tag with letter as well as showing the value in the "Count" variable and the result is the loop and its counter the statement and class and ID are ok

****Update
this is HTML code

```
<section class="words">
    <span class="sm-title">الف</span>
    <article class="word" id="A"> </article>
    <span class="sm-title">ب</span>
    <article class="word" id="B"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">پ</span>
    <article class="word" id="P"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ت</span>
    <article class="word" id="T"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ث</span>
    <article class="word" id="S"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ج</span>
    <article class="word" id="Jim"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">چ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ch"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ح</span>
    <article class="word" id="H"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">خ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Kh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">د</span>
    <article class="word" id="Dal"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ذ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-D"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ر</span>
    <article class="word" id="R"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ز</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ژ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Zh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">س</span>
    <article class="word" id="Sin"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ش</span>
    <article class="word" id="Shin"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ص</span>
    <article class="word" id="Sad"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ض</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-M"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ط</span>
    <article class="word" id="T-D"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ظ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-Z"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ع</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ein"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">غ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ghein"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ف</span>
    <article class="word" id="F"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ق</span>
    <article class="word" id="Gh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ک</span>
    <article class="word" id="Kam"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">گ</span>
    <article class="word" id="G"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ل</span>
    <article class="word" id="Lam"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">م</span>
    <article class="word" id="Mim"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ن</span>
    <article class="word" id="Noon"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">و</span>
    <article class="word" id="Vav"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ه</span>
    <article class="word" id="H-do-cheshm"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ی</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ya"></article>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you verified that the innerHTML is indeed empty?

Comment: `for (var Count = 0;Count<Word.length;Count++){` use let for variables like these that changes from time to time `let Count = 0;`

Comment: Could it be that the innerHTML consists of non-printing characters, such as a line break? Have you tried trimming the innerHTML in your if-statement?

Comment: Try using `Word[Count].innerHTML.trim()`

Comment: You should include your html in your question too.

Comment: yes i verified that tags are empty and non printing character dont exist cause if instead of chaning style i write this :Word[Count].innerHTML = 'This Section is Empty'; the code works fine only one of the article tags wont get this text and that one has a empty space in it

Comment: and btw i used let instead of var and it does not work in fact that was the first thing i did tried changing anything that is not needed outside of {} to "let" and i added the html code to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can tell your code works as you want to.  There's likely better ways to achieve the same thing as @imvain2 has pointed out.

However, here's your code pretty much verbatim and it's working.

```js
function AutoHider(){
   var Word = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
   for (var Count = 0;Count<Word.length;Count++){
    if(Word[Count].innerHTML === ""){
        Word[Count].style.display = 'none';
    }
   }
}

function AutoShower(){
   var Word = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
   for (var Count = 0;Count<Word.length;Count++){
    if(Word[Count].innerHTML === ""){
        Word[Count].style.display = '';
    }
   }
}
```

```css
article{
  height: 20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="AutoHider()">
Hide Empty Articles
</button>

<button onClick="AutoShower()">
Show Empty Articles
</button>

<section class="words">
    <span class="sm-title">الف</span>
    <article class="word" id="A"> </article>
    <span class="sm-title">ب</span>
    <article class="word" id="B"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">پ</span>
    <article class="word" id="P"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ت</span>
    <article class="word" id="T"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ث</span>
    <article class="word" id="S"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ج</span>
    <article class="word" id="Jim"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">چ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ch"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ح</span>
    <article class="word" id="H"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">خ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Kh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">د</span>
    <article class="word" id="Dal"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ذ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-D"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ر</span>
    <article class="word" id="R"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ز</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ژ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Zh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">س</span>
    <article class="word" id="Sin"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ش</span>
    <article class="word" id="Shin"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ص</span>
    <article class="word" id="Sad"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ض</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-M"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ط</span>
    <article class="word" id="T-D"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ظ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Z-Z"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ع</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ein"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">غ</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ghein"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ف</span>
    <article class="word" id="F"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ق</span>
    <article class="word" id="Gh"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ک</span>
    <article class="word" id="Kam"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">گ</span>
    <article class="word" id="G"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ل</span>
    <article class="word" id="Lam"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">م</span>
    <article class="word" id="Mim"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ن</span>
    <article class="word" id="Noon"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">و</span>
    <article class="word" id="Vav"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ه</span>
    <article class="word" id="H-do-cheshm"></article>
    <span class="sm-title">ی</span>
    <article class="word" id="Ya"></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and the :empty pseudoclass to hide divs with no content.

Although whitespace seems to be an issue:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

```css
.word{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:red;
}

.word:empty{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="word"></div>
<div class="word">CONTENT</div>
<div class="word"></div>
<div class="word">MORE CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok Sorry so i looked into the code turnes out everything was fine its just i mistaken the span tags i use as title with article itself and thaught its not hiding anything
i added a line of code and its fixed

```
function AutoHider(){
        var Word = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
        for (let Count = 0;Count<Word.length;Count++){
         if(Word[Count].innerHTML === ""){
             Word[Count].style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementsByClassName("sm-title")[Count].style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += Count + "<br/>";
         }
        }
}
```

its the last line from below now if an article tag is empty not only it hides it it hides the span tag class named as sm-title above it too thanks for your help regarding CSS solution